# Vanity URLs or masking mysiteName/sitepages/ to just the URL

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, alternate-access-mapping, url-rewriting

All my pages are having the urls

`www.domain.com/mysiteName/sitepages/Home.aspx
www.domain.com/mysiteName/sitepages/1.aspx
www.domain.com/mysiteName/sitepages/2.aspx
www.domain.com/mysiteName/sitepages/3.aspx` etc.

Instead I want to access them using

```
domain.com/Home.aspx 
domain.com/1.aspx 
domain.com/2.aspx 
domain.com/3.aspx
```

So in my pages, I will be coding to use `domain.com/Home.aspx` instead of `domain.com/mysiteName/sitepages/Home.aspx`.

I thought this can be done using a URLRewrite in IIS. I am not sure how to accomplish this?

Comment: what is the question then?

Comment: All my pages are having the urls 
www.domain.com/mysiteName/sitepages/Home.aspx<br/>
www.domain.com/mysiteName/sitepages/1.aspx
www.domain.com/mysiteName/sitepages/2.aspx
www.domain.com/mysiteName/sitepages/3.aspx etc.

Instead i want to access them using
https://www.domain.com/Home.aspx<br/>
https://www.domain.com/1.aspx
https://www.domain.com/2.aspx
https://www.domain.com/3.aspx


So in my pages, i will be coding to use 
https://www.domain.com/Home.aspx instead of
https://www.domain.com/mysiteName/sitepages/Home.aspx

I thought this can be done using a URLRewrite in IIS. I am not sure.

Comment: I want to have urls that dont show the /mysite/sitepages/

Comment: Try this link - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b76cf17d-85cb-4a5e-9f7b-e0efdf438667/add-alias-url-for-a-sharepoint-site

Comment: You don't mention the version of SharePoint, but SP2013 has taxonomy-based navigation that would solve this problem.

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

Their are couple of ways to cofnigure the Vanity URLs either OOTB(IIS) or 3rd party.

Configuring at IIS level: [How to create vanity URL for sub site](http://lindachapman.blogspot.com/2011/07/sharepoint-2010-how-to-create-vanity.html) she is talking about the subsite but true for site as well.

- Go to IIS.
- Go to SITES right click and ADD a Web Site.
- Name = SharePointVanityURLs  (This is so the App Pool can be named
  this, and they will all share the one app pool to save memory, you
  will rename this site to your first redirected hostname later)
- Create New Application Pool = SharePointVanityURLs
- Physical Path = `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\1stVanityName`
- Host Name: 1stVanityName
- OK
- Click on your new web site.
- Right click and select RENAME and change the name of the web site to
  1stVanityName.
- In the Actions Pane click Edit Permissions – Add Authenticated Users
  and click OK.
- Click on your new web site.
- In IIS section click Authentication – disable anonymous (unless using
  it) – enable Windows Authentication.
- Still focused on the Windows Authentication in the right pane click
  Advanced Settings and deselect Enable Kernel-mode authentication.
- Click on your new web site.
- In IIS section, click HTTP Redirect.
- Check Redirect requests to this destination.
- Enter your absolute URL to your sub-site without the home page
  entered.
- Check Redirect all requests to exact destination.
- In the right pane click Apply.
- Click on your new web site.
- Right click and select Manage Web Site – Restart.
- Enter a DNS record for this new vanity URL or short URL with an IP
  address that points to your Web Front End server or if using Load
  Balancing your VIP address.
- Flush DNS server cache and client cache if needing to test right
  away. Client is Command Prompt type IPCONFIG /flushdns .

Repeat steps above for each vanity URL, but the remain web sites on #4 select to use the existing App Pool “[SharePointVanityURLs](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26540.sharepoint-vanity-urls.aspx)” instead of creating new ones.

Or Use 3rd party tools:

[Jan Tielens’ URL Shortener Solution](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/url-shortening-for-sharepoint-2010)

[SharePoint URL Shortener](http://spurlshortener.codeplex.com/)

[SharePoint Joint Vanity URL](http://embraceware.com/blog/2014/05/new-sharepoint-products/)

[SharePoint ShortUrl](http://sharepointshorturl.com/)