# CQWP Search Result shows incorrect Item Link URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, xslt, content-query-web-part, hyperlink

Environment: SharePoint 2013

I`m using Gridview to display CQWP search data in Grid format with Link to the Title of the Item.

Using XSLT Template, I have the following code to have ITEM link associated with the Title of the Item searched.

'code'

It does shows the link but rather then just showing the Site URL for the List which is :

example: 
Expected URL: http://intranet.companyname.com/project/Lists/ProjectDashboard

However the search shows the respective Item ListURL and adds /2_.000
here is one of the result coming up-
http://intranet.companyname.com/project/Lists/ProjectDashboard/2_.000

I want to get rid of "/2_.000"

Please suggest how can I?

Answer (score 0):

Added modified SafelinkURL code in Itemstyle.xsl as

'code'

'code'

reference the SAFeLinkURL in the appropriate site column as :

'code'

                
                 
                
           
'code'

Answer (score 0):

There is another post regarding vanity URL's. This outlines ways to rewrite your URLs on the IIS.
[Link to post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137389/vanity-urls-or-masking-mysitename-sitepages-to-just-the-url)